# JQuery: Add events stored in MySQL in responsive jQuery calendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to fetch Date-wise events list from MySQL and pass to the following function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
    time: '2013-05',
    events: {
      "2013-04-30": {
        "number": 5,
        "badgeClass": "badge-warning",
        "url": "http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar"
      },
      "2013-04-26": {
        "number": 1,
        "badgeClass": "badge-warning",
        "url": "http://w3widgets.com"
      },
      "2013-05-03": {
        "number": 1,
        "badgeClass": "badge-error"
      },
      "2013-06-12": {}
    }
  });
});
```

How to get Event list from MySQL in above format and pass it to events constructor in above function.

I pass one javascript variable as Event list but it is not working.

Comment: Hi there! The stackoverflow community enjoys helping out developers achieve their goals, with the premise of helping one's self first. In that regard, have a look at this [link][1] to help you better formulate your question, show your work and help us help you in general. Thanks!


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

i will however at least point you to the right direction. If you want an ajax query to retrieve this data in this format, you will need a php script to return the json object you have here in your responsiveCalendar constructor.

Comment: once you have the script that generates said json object, you will need to run your ajax request on document ready. then on the callback (assuming success), you will be able to init your calendar. once you have a more specific question that shows actual work, edit your question, and ill get back to you